# Is there a way to deploy userscripts to Grease/Tampermonkey outside of a browser?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

For convenience's sake, I'd like to edit some userscripts I'm working on as part of a larger project in my IDE, IntelliJ.  I like having everything together in one project.  A bit of a hitch I'm running into is that if I want to deploy a script from IntelliJ, I have to add a new script with the name I want to *monkey, and then overwrite it on deployment.  It's a little bit frustrating, but I haven't found a way to deploy a completely new userscript outside of a browser.  Is this possible?  Or am I just going to have to settle for my workaround?

Comment: you can use a tiny userscript to inject a whole script file from anywhere. this lets you push updates to the script as well, but it also requires the user to be online. this remote injection can also be accomplished by a bookmarklet to get the same effect, making such scripts more portable.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought of that.  I might give that a shot, might make developing easier.  Wonder if that'd make debugging more interesting, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can you a user script which includes the code of your project using

http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require

```
// add this to the beginning of your code.

$.getScript('http://example.com/testing.js?' + new Date().getSeconds());
```

/edited/

Now this contact's the server for the file with a unique name / arguments (sorry i don't know what the '?' arguments is called, GET http request method maybe) each time.

//
this loads the code from ^ the designated url when your userscript is run on Your target website.

Comment: this goes in the "metadata block" of your userscript in *monkey.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I follow.  Does @include designate which sites the script should be active on?

Comment: But, this only loads the script once. After that it is not updated unless the name changes... So not very useful for this situation.